# simple SED command

Tags: regex, sed

I have a html report that comes out of a program we use. Its extremely plain html and id like to work on fixing it up just a bit.

What code would I need to do in sed to replace

```
<html>  with

<html><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="LivingInStyle.css">
```

Thanks,
Russ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use:

```
sed -e 's!<html>!<html><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="LivingInStyle.css">!' < file
```

i.e. use another separator instead of escaping the slash.

Answer (score 8):

```
sed 's/<html>/<html><link rel="stylesheet" type="text\/css" href="LivingInStyle.css">/g' file.html
```

That will output the new file to the console and you can redirect it wherever you need.  Or you can use -i to edit inplace.

EDIT:  Forgot to escape the slash

Comment: I'd choose a different delimiter, maybe 's!...!...!g', to avoid having to escape.  But that's personal opinion.

Comment: @ephemient: That's probably a better choice, but I feel odd using anything but slash